# Disable enter key press in type button

Tags: javascript, html

How do you disable enter press in a button?

I am making a game where you press a button, and then a counter counts you presses and displays text, the problem is when you hold down the enter key the counter goes up fast... Here is the game: "http://gorillapps.net/games/Button-Clicker.html".

So how do you disable a key press which is default in Javascript?

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("countButton").onkeydown = function(e){
if (e.which == 13) //13 is the keycode referring to enter.
    {
       e.preventDefault(); //this will prevent the intended purpose of the event. 
       return false; //return false on the event.
    }
}
```

This prevents execution of the button by enter.

Advanced solution. Enter is only allowed one time. User has to let go of the enter button to reset.

```
var enterPressed = 0;
document.getElementById("countButton").onkeydown = function(e){
    if (e.which == 13)
        {
        if (!enterPressed)
        {
            enterPressed = 1;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }


    }
}

document.getElementById("countButton").onkeyup = function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        enterPressed = 0;

    }
}
```

Normally I would advocate the use of `addEventListener`, however this is such a simple website, with only one purpose, that inline events aren't a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$('#yourButtonId').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: Keypress won't register an enter. Use keydown.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to use jQuery, Use vanilla JS.